# How to count the Strings, numbers, and doubles in a script from the users' input (Scanner) in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, counter

I'm a beginner and I have tried a few different ways from the stuff that I have learned from other people's questions, but I think my problem with the following problem is that I can't figure out the logic of my code. If someone can suggest a solution with explaining the logic of the codes, I would greatly appreciate it.
I'm supposed to create a method in the format of method() that will prompt the user to enter a script that includes String, numbers, and doubles. The method should count the number of Strings, numbers, and doubles and prints out the list of the string, numbers and doubles. I have got the part that the method prints the list of the strings, numbers and doubles, but it seems I can't get the counter to count them. I have got this so far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Games {

    private Scanner input;

 public Games() {

  input = new Scanner(System.in);

 }

 public void textParser() {

  System.out.println("Enter a Script");
  int intCount = 0;
  int dblCount = 0;
  int strCount = 0;

  while(input.hasNext()) {
   if(input.hasNextInt()) {
    int num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(num);
    intCount++;
 }else if(input.hasNextDouble()) {
   double value = input.nextDouble();
   System.out.println(value);
   dblCount++;
 }else {
   String oneWord = input.next();
   System.out.println(oneWord);
   strCount++;
 }
}

System.out.println("Number of integers: " + intCount);
System.out.println("Number of doubles: " + dblCount);
System.out.println("Number of strings: " + strCount);


}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Games demo = new Games();
  demo.textParser();
 }

}
```

Example of expected inputs and outputs:

```
 Enter a Script
 32 quick brown foxes jump over 65 lazy dogs and few doubles are 43.3 
 and 76.9

 32
 65
 Number of integers: 2
 43.3
 76.9
 Number of doubles: 2
 quick
 brown 
 foxes 
 jump 
 over
 lazy 
 dogs 
 and 
 few 
 doubles 
 are
 and
 Number of strings: 12
```

Actual output:

```
 32
 65
 43.3
 76.9
 quick
 brown 
 foxes 
 jump 
 over
 lazy 
 dogs 
 and 
 few 
 doubles 
 are
 and
```

Comment: `hasNext()` will block until the input stream is closed (`EOF`). You can send ctrl-d to exit the loop.

Comment: What is your actual output?

Comment: If the script is all one line, you can read the entire line with `Scanner.nextLine()`, then `split()` it on space. Then for each item, try to convert to `int`. If that fails, try to convert to double. If that fails, assume it is a string.

Comment: @Schred I have added an example

Comment: @NomadMaker The actual outs are just the list of integers, doubles, and Strings. Just the counters are not working

Comment: What does that mean "they are not working"? Are they all `0`?

Comment: Comments like this are why putting the actual outputs along with the expected outputs is necessary to helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the beginning, you say `while(scanner.hasNext()`. This means, that all the code in the loop will be excecuted pretty much as long as the program runs.

You have put the statements that print the counters outside of the loop, and designed your  code in a way, that you will never leave that loop.

So you need some kind of exit condition. Let's say, if one of the strings is `exit`, you exit the loop and print the counters:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        // ...
    } else if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        // ...
    } else {
        String oneWord = input.next();
        System.out.println(oneWord);
        strCount++;

        if (oneWord.equals("exit")) {
            input.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or, if you don't want to have to put "exit" in there, do this:

```
int intCount = 0, doubleCount = 0, stringCount = 0;

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] segments = input.nextLine().split(" ");

    for (String segment : segments) {
        System.out.println(segment);

        try {
            int asInt = Integer.parseInt(segment);
            intCount++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            try {
                double asDouble = Double.parseDouble(segment);
                doubleCount++;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
                stringCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Number of integers: " + intCount);
    System.out.println("Number of doubles: " + doubleCount);
    System.out.println("Number of strings: " + stringCount);
}
```

Comment: thank you. Just one thing that I wanted to ask. What "NumberFormatException" is supposed to do here? Does this declare the format of the e and e2?

Comment: That's just the type of exception the `parse` methods throw. If you don't know what exceptions are yet, that's no problem, you'll learn it later. ;D

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner will continue to read until it finds an "end of file" condition.

As you're reading from stdin, that'll either be when you send an EOF character (usually ^d on Unix) or at the end of the file if you use < style redirection.

You need some kind of exit condition

```
if (oneWord.equals("exit")) {
            input.close();
            break;
 }
```

Another approach after giving your input Ctrl+Z it will send EOF.